# Execution permissions in Python

Tags: python, security, permissions, execute

I need to send code to remote clients to be executed in them but security is a concern for me right now. I don't want unsafe code to be executed there so I would like to control what a program is doing. I mean for example, know if is making connections, where is connecting to, if is reading local files, etc. Is this possible with Python?

EDIT: I'm thinking in something similar to Android permission system. I want to know what a code will do and if it does something different, stop it.

Comment: "send code to remote clients to be executed in them" and "don't want any code to be executed there" seems to contradict each other.

Comment: Sorry. I wanted to say "unsafe".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a different Python runtime:

- if you run your script using [Jython](http://www.jython.org/); you can exploit Java's permission system
- with [Pypy's sandboxed version](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/sandbox.html) you can choose what is allowed to run in your controller script

Comment: Nice lateral thinking +1 - possibly even IronPython with the .NET permission system

Comment: @JonClements Is a nice approach. I want clients to be portable so use Java to develop these clients and run the scripts with Jython is a good possibility. Can you point me to an article about Java permission system? I've never heard about it before. Are you sure that it's possible to integrate it with Python? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidMorenoGarcía I can't take credit - it's J.F. Sebestian's answer. Jython is a Python implementation that runs on the JVM. So yes, but I'm afraid to say that it's up to you now to Google and find relevant articles!

Comment: Yeah, I know what Jython is although I've never used it. I'm only asking if is it possible to integrate Jython with the Java permission system. Of course I'm searching in Google about this system.

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a module in Python called `bastian`, but that was deprecated as it wasn't *that* secure. There's also I believe something called `RPython`, but I don't know too much about that.

I would in this case use [Pyro](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pyro4) and write the code on the target server. That way you know clients can only execute written and tested code.

**edit** - it's probably worth noting that Pyro also supports http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_separation - although I've not had to use it for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a sandboxed python. There used to be an effort to implement this, but it has been abolished a couple of years ago.

[Sandboxed python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/SandboxedPython) in the python wiki offers a nice overview of possible options for your usecase.

Comment: No, I'm thinking in something like Android permissions. I want to know what a code will do and if it does something different, stop it.

Comment: You can realize that using sandboxed python by only exposing allowed APIs to the sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

The most rigourous (but probably the slowest) way is to run Python on a bare OS in an emulator.

Depending on the OS you use, there are several ways of running programs with restrictions, but without the overhead of an emulator:

- FreeBSD has a nice integrated solution in the form of [jails](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/jails-intro.html).
  These grew out of the [`chroot`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) system call.
- [Linux-VServer](http://linux-vserver.org/Welcome_to_Linux-VServer.org) aims to do more or less the same on Linux.

Comment: Permissions would be set for each code and the clients would be portable, so its not a solution. As I said in other comment I'm searching for something similar to the Android permissions system. Now what a code will do and stop it if it does something different.